# Kik API for android

Tags: android

I can't find KIK API for Android. Anyone has a link to share please ?
Or if they don't provide it any more, I'd like a link stating the reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late, but is this what you're looking for?
http://kik.com/dev/quickstart.php

Comment: Yes it is. It didn't exist yet when I asked. Thank you.